# What does __setattr__ do in this python code?

Tags: python, get, set

this is my code:

```
class fun:

    def __getattr__(self,key):
        return self[key]

    def __setattr__(self,key,value):
        self[key] = value+1
a = fun()
a['x']=1
print a['x']
```

and the error is :

```
AttributeError: fun instance has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

when i change it to :

```
class fun:

    def __getattr__(self,key):
        return self.key

    def __setattr__(self,key,value):
        self.key = value+1
a = fun()
a.x=1
print a.x
```

the error is :

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

what can I do, I want get `2`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `self.key = ...` invokes `__setattr__`, so you end up in an infinite recursion. To use `__setattr__`, you have to access the object's field some other way. There are two common solutions:

```
def __setattr__(self,key,value):
    # Access the object's fields through the special __dict__ field
    self.__dict__[key] = value+1

# or...

def __init__(self):
    # Assign a dict field to access fields set via __[gs]etattr__
    self.attrs = {}

def __setattr__(self,key,value):
    self.attrs[key] = value+1
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a typo.

You want to implement the special method `__setattr__`, and not `__serattr__` which has no special meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the method is called [`__setattr__()`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/attribute-access.html). It is when an attribute assignment is attempted. Such as when you do:

```
self[key] = value+1
```

...making your particular call (infinitely) recursive!

A better way to do this would be to derive your class from `object`, a so-called [new-style class](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/node33.html) and call the base class:

```
class fun(object):

    def __setattr__(self,key,value):
        super(fun, self).__setattr__(key, value + 1)

a = fun()
a.x=1
print a.x
```

I removed your `__getattr__()` implementation, since it did nothing of any value.